# Unity UI, complx slider, how do I do this?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, slider

I'm working on a project and I'm currently stuck at the GUI. I'm trying to make a bar like in the picture: a white circle is slowly filled up with beer but the beer image should move up instead of stretching, the image is squared because at every moment it should fill horizontally the white circle, but should not go outside the white circle.
I made the slider fill bottom to top, then assigned the beer image to the Fill area and set Preserv Aspect so it doesn't stretch, but I don't know how to go on. How do I proceed? Thanks in advance for the help.

[image: Bar exemple]

Comment: Working around I managed to move the image up and down, the only problem left is to "cut" the beer part outside the white circle

Comment: You can use Mask for cut outside parts. see 
[this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-mask)